# Recursive possible all paths finder

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

For example I have points like this:

```
[[4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6], [5, 4], [6, 5], [7, 5]]
```

I want to find all POSSIBLE paths. It can start from every single point if it fits the criteria.

I mean with possible is: In result array there can not be a point that doesn't touch its previous or next point.  `[4, 5] [7, 5] [7, 6]`
is not possible because i indexes(4 and 7) are not touching. `[4, 6] [5, 4]`
is not possible because j indexes(6 and 4) are not touching.

At the end I try to have something like this:

```
[[[4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]],
[[4, 6], [5, 6], [6, 6]],
[[5, 6], [4, 6], [4, 5], [5, 4], [6, 5], [7, 5]]
```

I tried to achieve this with recursion like this. This is a working python code but nothing close to what i want for now :)

```py
points_array = [[4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6],
                [5, 4], [6, 5], [7, 5]]

possible_points = []


def find_all_possible_paths(left_points,
                            start_point,
                            current_path):
    if len(left_points) == 0:
        if len(current_path) > 3:
            possible_points.append(current_path)
        return

    is_left_any_touching_point = False

    for point in left_points:
        #Take prev_start_point and current_point indexes
        start_point_i = start_point[0]
        start_point_j = start_point[1]

        current_point_i = point[0]
        current_point_j = point[1]

        # IF POINTS ARE TOUCHING add it to list and continue recursion
        if abs(current_point_i - start_point_i) \
                <= 1 and abs(current_point_j - start_point_j) <= 1:
            is_left_any_touching_point = True
            current_path.append(point)
            left_points.remove(point)
            find_all_possible_paths(left_points, point, current_path)

    if not is_left_any_touching_point:
        if len(current_path) > 3:
            possible_points.append(current_path)
        return


#For every start point, try to find every possible paths (We delete start point)
for i in range(0, len(points_array) - 1):
    temp_array = points_array.copy()
    del temp_array[i]
    find_all_possible_paths(temp_array, points_array[i], [])


print(possible_points)
```

Comment: What does this structure `[[4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6], [5, 4], [6, 5], [7, 5]]` means? Is it a list of 2D Coordinates? Or is it saying something like, at `[4, 5]`, node 4 leads to node 5?

Comment: @CarlHR I'm pretty sure that it is a list of points.  A point `[i1, j1]` touches `[i2, j2]` iff `abs(i1 - i2) <= 1` and `abs(j1 - j2) <= 1`.  At least that is what the code says.

Comment: Yes, after reading the OP's description more carefully it seems that you're right. The strucuture references points in a 2D grid, and the pathfinding takes in consideration that you cannot make any diagonal adjacent movements.

Comment: @CarlHR Yes it's 2d coordinates. Imagine 8x8 board and [4, 5] means:  i index is 4 and j index is 5.

Comment: Should paths have some target, or some minimal length? Is a single pair considered a path? If I have a valid path, are all slices of that path also valid paths?

Comment: @trincot Minimal length is 3. The target is to find longest possible paths and compare which one is most efficient with my algorithm. So for optimization reasons if we have 30 points, we can start combining paths from minimum length 15.

Comment: Elsewhere you write about 99.99%, so you seem to want to apply an *heuristic*. So what would happen in 00.01% of the cases? This question becomes a bit fuzzy.... I think I will leave it to others.

Comment: @trincot I mean we can ignore tiny reliability issues for huge performance improvements.

Comment: Yes, I got that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your criteria, the following should work.

That said, I may misunderstand your criteria since I'm finding a lot of paths that your code does not.  But the paths look like they follow the stated rules.

```
def path_iter(points):
    point_tree = {}
    for point in points:
        if point[0] not in point_tree:
            point_tree[point[0]] = set()
        point_tree[point[0]].add(point[1])

    def recur (path):
        yielded = False
        i, j = path[-1]
        for i1 in [i-1, i, i+1]:
            if i1 in point_tree:
                for j1 in [j-1, j, j+1]:
                    if j1 in point_tree[i1] and [i1, j1] not in path:
                        path.append([i1, j1])
                        yield from recur(path)
                        path.pop()
                        yielded = True
        if not yielded and 3 < len(path):
            yield list(path)

    for point in points:
        yield from recur([point])

for path in path_iter(points_array):
    print(path)
```

Comment: You understood the criteria correctly no problem with that. This code works just fine with small sample sizes thank you. But for example when I have points_array with length of 25-30 like points_array = [[0, 5], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [3, 7], [2, 7], [3, 4], [3, 3], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 5], [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4]]
this code takes forever to execute and I think there is no way to optimize. My main target with finding all paths is this: I want to find all longest paths and compare them with my algorithm.

Comment: Actually, We %99.99 of times can assume that if we have 30 points, longest paths will contain at least 15-16 points. So we  can start the iteration with grouping them and then look for further points. So for optimization reasons if we have 30 points, we can start combining paths from minimum length 15.Do you think this approach could optimize the code ?

Comment: @ahmetnecdeto Ah. You're trying to solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem.  There is no known efficient solution and not much hope of one because it is NP-complete.